# Sequence of measurable functions is convergent a.e then there exists a subsequence that is absolutely convergent a.e

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Question: Let $f_n\colon [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ be measurable functions so that $\lim_{n \to \infty} f_n(x) = 0$ for a.e. $x \in [0,1]$. Show that there exists a sequence $(a_n)_n \subset \mathbb{R}$ so that $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = \infty$ and that $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n f_n(x) =0$ for a.e. $x \in [0,1]$.

My attempt: I am able to prove there exists a sequence $(b_n)\subset \mathbb{R}_{>0}$ so that $\lim_{n\to \infty} b_n =\infty$ and $\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{f_n(x)}{b_n} =0$ for a.e. $x \in [0,1]$ using the Borel-Cantelli's lemma. However, the sequence $(1/b_n)$ then tends to $0$ instead of $\infty$. Is there anyway I can use Borel-Cantelli's lemma to obtain a sequence then tends to $\infty$ instead? Any hints/solutions provided are appreciated.

Comment: Question is wrong. The conclusion only holds for a  subsequence, as you have in the title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the question in the title here are some hints:

$f_n \to 0$ in measure, so there exist $k_1<k_2<...$ such that $\lambda ((|f_k| > \frac 1 {n^{2}})<\frac  1 {n^{2}}$ for $k \geq k_n$. In particular, this holds with $k=k_n$. By Borel Cantelli Lemma there is a null set outside which  $n^{2}|f_{k_n}| \leq 1$ for $n$ sufficiently large. So $nf_{k_n} \to 0$ a.e. Take $a_n=n$.

Comment: thank you for the hints